# Is there any package and function that produce this image in R?

Tags: r, plot, distribution, correlation, scatter-plot

Is there any package that produce this image in R?
[image: The image]

I wanna see correlation, distribution and scatter plot of some variable.

Comment: Honestly, while this is certainly a programming question and sort of belongs here, you'll probably have better luck through the statistics portal at http://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: May be you wanna have a look at ggplot2, GGally. They may not give you the exact. But very close.

Comment: I love it, GGally is great.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use

```
 library(psych)
 pairs.panels(iris[,-5], hist.col="white", scale=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This plot can be constructed entirely from the examples given under `?pairs`.

```
panel.hist <- function(x, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(usr[1:2], 0, 1.5) )
  h <- hist(x, plot = FALSE)
  breaks <- h$breaks; nB <- length(breaks)
  y <- h$counts; y <- y/max(y)
  rect(breaks[-nB], 0, breaks[-1], y, ...)
}

panel.cor <- function(x, y, digits = 2, prefix = "", cex.cor, ...) {
  usr <- par("usr"); on.exit(par(usr))
  par(usr = c(0, 1, 0, 1))
  r <- abs(cor(x, y))
  txt <- format(c(r, 0.123456789), digits = digits)[1]
  txt <- paste0(prefix, txt)
  if(missing(cex.cor)) cex.cor <- 0.8/strwidth(txt)
  text(0.5, 0.5, txt, cex = cex.cor * r)
}

pairs(iris, lower.panel=panel.smooth, upper.panel=panel.cor, 
      diag.panel=panel.hist)
```

[image]